# how to toggle focus on terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to keep the terminal open and let the code regain the focus?

```
ctrl+`
```

does the trick, but it also hides it away. I want the terminal to keep it open, but unfocused.

Comment: You want to open the terminal but keep an editor focused?

Comment: Just press `CTRL` + `1` after you open it... or whatever your shortcut is to focus the editor of choice

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
    "key": "shift+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  }
```

does the trick :-)